# Angular: ng-repeat and <object> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I have a set of icons I want to load display using ng-repeat. The problem is that generating the svg tags doesn't play nice with most browsers (Some icons not being rendered in Chrome, Safari doesn't display them at all, scrolling in Chrome is blocked when the page is loaded). Is there a better way to do this?

```
<div class="wrap" ng-repeat="icon in icons">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/icons/{{icon.iconImg}}.svg" class="icon">SVG NOT LOADED</object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the svgicons as img-tags

```
<div class="wrap" ng-repeat="icon in icons">
    <img ng-src="img/icons/{{icon.iconImg}}.svg" class="icon"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it doesn't change anything. Still can't load all icons properly.

Comment: To add some more detail: It now won't load 4 images and prints this in console for each one of them "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/xml"

Comment: I cleared the browser cache and now it work fine. Thanks for help.